# Слитное или раздельное написание наречий: "мне не*страшно" и т. п

Tags: слитно-раздельно, наречия, частица-не

Как пишется *не* в примерах:

- Мне не*страшно.
- Мне не*весело.
- Мне не*холодно.

Приведите правило. Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенных вами примерах возможно как слитное,так и раздельное написание частицы **не**.

- Мне нестрашно (безопасно).
- Мне невесело (грустно).
- Мне нехолодно (тепло).
- Мне не страшно, а спокойно.
- Мне не весело, а грустно.
- Мне не холодно, а жарко.

Правило таково.

1. Пишется слитно частица не с наречиями, которые без отрицательной частицы не употребляются: неизбежно, нелепо, недоумевающе.
2. Пишется слитно частица не с наречиями на -о, которые в сочетании с отрицательной частицей **приобретают противоположное значение (обычно такие слова можно заменить синонимами без не): неплохо (ср. хорошо); немного (ср. мало); неудачно (ср. безуспешно).**
3. Пишется раздельно частица не с наречиями **на -о, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление: живут не богато, а бедно; обычно ехали не быстро и не медленно; не часто возникает подобная ситуация; не скоро ещё вскроется река; не случайно он завёл этот разговор; не вечно будет природа хранить свои тайны от человека; не сладко жилось переселенцам на первых порах; Говоря честно, не много найдётся людей, которые не испытывают неприятного чувства при виде пауков.**

См. : [Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81)

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, но стоило бы ещё упомянуть про сочетания вида "отнюдь не", "вовсе не", "нисколько не". В этом случае частица "не" будет писаться **раздельно**, напр., "мне нисколько не страшно".

Answer (score 2):

**Это предикативные наречия (их относят к словам категории состояния), они выполняют роль сказуемого в безличных предложениях.**

Во многих случаях НЕ с предикативными наречиями может писаться **как слитно, так и раздельно** (авторский выбор: утверждение или отрицание признака), например:
Невесело (не весело) было у него на душе.

[Розенталь: §71. Правописание не с наречиями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_09)

В то же время **некоторые предикативные наречия пишутся только раздельно** с НЕ, так как не соотносятся с полной формой прилагательного.

**Схема** их образования такова: страшный ― страшно ― не страшно, холодный ― холодно ― не холодно.

Comment: Можно поподробнее про "некоторые предикативные наречия пишутся только раздельно с НЕ, так как не соотносятся с полной формой прилагательного"?