НЕ с наречием слитно или раздельно тут?
Надеяться на манну небесную не(?)эффективно.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434180/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%82-%d0%bf/434183#434183

Правила я прочитала, прежде тут спросить. Хотела, чтоб рассмотрели именно это предложение и ответили мне :)

Что же в нём такого, что требует особого разбора?

Оно мне непонятно.
